# Need of order relation in the definition of measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

The following excerpt has been taken from Bartle's "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure"

[image]

Bartle's definition of measurable function uses the order relation $>$. Nonetheless, the union of the sets $A_\alpha$ and $B_\alpha$ should result in $\left\{x \in X \right\}$, as every $f(x)$ will be either smaller, equal to or larger than a real number $\alpha$.

So, can the definition of a measurable function be restated as the following proposition?

"A function $f$ on X to R is said to be measurable if the set $\left\{x \in X \right\}$ belongs to **X**"

Comment: No because "the set $\left\{x \in X \right\}$ belongs to **X**" doesn't say anything about $f$ and is therefore true or false regardless of $f$. It would in other word make all $f$ on X to R either measurable or all non-measurable.

Comment: The statements (a),(b),(c),(d) are equivalent, but there is no reason at all to think that they are equivalent with "your" statement. They are not. The part after "if" in your statement does not even mention function $f$, so says nothing about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, that $A\in X$ and $B\in X$ doesn't generally mean that $A\cup B\in X$, and for the set of measurable sets $X$ it doesn't folllow $A\cup B\in X$ than $A\in X$. You can for example pick an non-measurable set $A$ and se that $A\cup\overline A \in X$, but still $A\notin X$.